# How to get scroll position of a pdf in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to get the scroll position of iframe when viewing a pdf file?

Also is it possible to disable the scroll in iframe and make the height of iframe equal to the length of the pdf file?

Comment: I think the answer to both is `no` as a PDF is not HTML and does not work as an inline element, so theres no way for the DOM to know anything about this. PDF's aren't even naturally displayed in-browser, they use a plugin most of the time...